# AngularJS: show loader when component's template is loading

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was wondering how can I catch the loading event of the template of the component.

I have set up a global http interceptor which is working fine but not when component is loading the template.

Here is a component example:

```
var RequestSummaryCtrl = (function () {

    function RequestSummaryCtrl() {
    }

    RequestSummaryCtrl.prototype.deleteRequest = function () {
        var that = this;
        this.requests = this.requests.filter(function (request) { return request.id !== that.request.id; });
    };

    return RequestSummaryCtrl;
}());

var requestSummaryComponent = {

    templateUrl: getTemplateUrl + "/request-summary",
    controller: RequestSummaryCtrl,
    bindings: {
        request: "=",
        requests: "=?",
        manualForm: "@"
    }
};
```

I can sometimes see delay for the apparition of the component.

Thank you